# Using accessibility to store other info?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiaccessibility

In my application I want to have the UILabel to hold two strings (one for showing and other for using sometime later time) for my application. while thinking of subclassing I came across the property `accessibilityValue` for all UIElements. I don't know if it is for that purpose. So Guide me that if I can use the `accessibilityValue` for my purpose or I should go for some other way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you really shouldn't do that. `accessibilityValue` is used for VoiceOver, and even if you don't care about your users that use it (and *needs*) it, it's still a bad OO practice.

Go on and subclass it.

Comment: Why you would even need to subclass it is beyond me, you should just keep the second string in the ViewController and set it from there.

Comment: Yes, you can. But depending on how he need to use its value (i.e. if the label needs to know both value), he'll need to subclass. It's similar to `UIImageView`'s `highlightedImage`.

Comment: Still the label is a view and in MVC this should not contain data, it is just a representation of the data in model. I do agree that using the `accessibilityValue` is wrong and subclassing is a better option. but I would just like to stress that you should try and solve the problem in a MVC way. Where you change the model to hold the data and not the View.